# How to startup a oracle database with sql plus or with any developer tool without connecting to the Database

Tags: windows, oracle, plsql

How to startup a database without connecting to Database. Actually what I did is I shutdown my database and then my sql plus screen hanged and so closed unhandled.

then I tried to connect my database then I got **ORA-12514** error.

I checked my database service in Services.msc -- it is working and I restarted my service as well. I check tnsname.ora file as well.

May be solution of 
ORA-12514: 
TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Comment: Have you already tried the [following](http://ora-12514.ora-code.com/)?

Comment: How are you connecting (or trying to) at the moment? Are you sure the database is down and you have the right service name? Can you access the database server to check `lsnrctl services` or connect to the database locally, which you'll need to be able to do to start the database if it is down?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d)

Comment: @alex Thanks for the reply.when I ran lsnrctl, and so I checked with status command my service name is not coming. but DB services is running in services.msc

Comment: @abhi I tried that link as well as implemented all the resolutions. but doesn't really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

normally you need a statically defined listener for this. So, in the listener.ora add the entries defining your instance. Next to that you need a remote passwordfile setup

```
remote_login_passwordfile = exclusive
```

to allow remote sys connects (don't forget the "as sysdba" part)